# Angular 11 Apollo graphql - WARNING: heuristic fragment matching going on! - Missing Field Warning

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, angular11

I'm calling an API where a field is optional and for some records it will not exists so it won't return e.g:

```
...
media_gallery {
    url
    label,
    ... on ProductVideo {
         video_content {
          video_url
       }
    }
 } 
 ...
```

In this case above `video_content` object for some record it will not return. I've searched the web and apply various possible fix but not luck, one being fragments and possible types ref:https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/fragments/#fragment-matcher, apply all of them without errors but the issue still persists.

Anyone has any idea how to make apollo understand that this field is optional?

Thanks

Comment: Fragments are used to combine data from different pieces of your graph (e.g. if ProductVideo was a subset of another type). Your graph should return any available value that's returned via a resolver, the only requirement is to make the field nullable in the schema.

If you share reproducible steps to re-create the issue there may be additional advice that could be shared as well.

Answer (score 0):

To use a fragment, first define the interface that each type implements to represent their relationship. As a minimal example:

```
"Represents media_gallery's common attributes"
interface media_gallery {
  url: String!
  "The media_gallery url"
  label: String!
  "The media_gallery label"
}
```

The implementing types will need to include these fields and return types, as well as the new fields they need:

```
type ProductVideo implements media_gallery {
  url: String!
  "The media_gallery URL"
  label: String!
  "The media_gallery label"
  video_content: String!
  "Product Video's description"
  video_url: String!
  "URL to the Product Video"
}
```

Once these are defined, create the necessary resolvers to determine which type matches the interface implementation returned. From there, fragment composition can be added:

```
"Declared fragment"
query getMediaGallery {
  media_gallery {
    url
    label
    ...ProductVideoContent
  }
}

fragment ProductVideoContent on ProductVideo {
  video_content {
    video_url
  }
}

"Inline fragment"
query getMediaGallery {
  media_gallery {
    url
    label
    ... on ProductVideo {
      video_content {
        video_url
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Some additional resources on using fragments:
[Apollo Odyssey tutorial for Intermediate Schema Design](https://www.apollographql.com/tutorials/side-quest-intermediate-schema-design/interfaces), [dev doc on semantically meaningful interfaces](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/enterprise-guide/federated-schema-design/#create-semantically-meaningful-interfaces), [Using fragments with unions and interfaces](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/fragments/#using-fragments-with-unions-and-interfaces).